# Заблокировать просмотр каталога

Tags: .htaccess, php

В-общем, на моем сайте в каталоге с шаблоном можно легко открыть папку с картинками, вот так  http://prntscr.com/1jqe0r

Как заблокировать возможность вот так смотреть файлы?

Answer (score 3):

Делается это записью в `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
```